# How to add field to all documents in database mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to add a field to all documents in the database, but I am not sure how to do that. Here is my database

```
      const db = client.schema
```

How would I update all documents and add a field called tiks (number) in it?

Answer (score 4):

```
db.yourCollection.update(
  {},
  { $set: {"newField": 1} },
  false,
  true
)
```

Parameters

1. Collection to update since you want all {}
2. Field to set
3. Upsert - only add when it is not there hence false
4. Multi - update multiple documents if matches to query hence true