# All Documents not updating mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

client.schema is the name of my collection

When i run this code:

```
client.schema.update(
  {},
  { $set: {"newField": 1} },
  false,
  true
)
```

It doesn't create a new field in every document called newField, but instead returns this error:

```
MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got true
```

How would I add the field to all documents?

Comment: have you checked the function definition? Your 4th parameter is expected to be a function, not a boolean value

Comment: Someone told me to say true for this reason:
Multi - update multiple documents if matches to query hence true

Comment: I think you are taking about https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.update

Comment: Here is where I was told to do this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991659/how-to-add-field-to-all-documents-in-database-mongoose?noredirect=1#comment121933222_68991659

Answer (score 0):

```
client.schema.update(
  {},
  { $set: {"newField": 1} },
  {upsert:false,multi:true} 
)
```

You should add newField to your schema

Comment: No fields are added to any documents when I do that

Comment: I said you should add newField to schema